# Install Android Studio software without admin privileges on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I'm trying to install Android Studio software to work, on a company machine which has no admin rights. Can I install Android Studio software without admin rights?

I tried direct extraction using `7zip`, no luck.
I tried spoofing admin account, no luck.

I'm using Windows 7 machine, connected to a company network with my only ID that can login to the system.

Why don't Android Studio just run like `Eclipse` does it, huh!

Does any know how can this be achieved?

EDIT:
FYI when I tried using `7zip`:
[image]

Comment: Why should you be able to simply unzip an executable setup routine? I would expect that at most with a self-extracting archive, but not with a setup... Why didn't you just ask your admin if he installs it for you or how you can do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, I did same thing what you want. 
I downloaded android studio from

```
http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-3-0
```

unzip it and run studio which located in bin/Studio64.exe

It's working great, remember you need java installed to run it.

You can choose type of channels mention in same link under [Download](http://tools.android.com/download)

[image]

[image]

You do not get SDK with this, so go to [download sdk only](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)  and download sdk from there [image]

Open your android studio, go to project structure in file menu, change the sdk location to your downloaded sdk path. That's it. Now every thing is setup.

Comment: Unzipping using `7zip` doesn't work my friend. You get errors, a lot.

Comment: It might be a problem with you 7zip. Am running android studio with above mention procedure. can you post what errors you are gettings ?

Comment: Hope your extraction .exe file. You can download .zip file what I mention in answer. and have try it.

Comment: @zIronManBox
Can you download sdk from : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html 
Go to SDK Tools only section and select android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip 
After download just paste you downloaded file location to SDK path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107128/discussion-between-kathi-sai-prathap-reddy-and-zironmanbox).

Comment: Download link broken.

Comment: @Mohd.Umar added working link and its error image you can choose stable version to download it.

Comment: I downloaded `android-studio-ide-171.4408382-windows.zip` file and extracted it with 7zip. Then ran the executable file at `C:\Users\me\Downloads\android-studio-ide-171.4408382-windows\android-studio\bin\studio64.exe` and a wizard showed up and it automatically downloaded all SDK. Everything went on smoothly and there was no need to download SDK zip file separately. The default SDK location for auto-download is `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`. Thanks for your help